# c# Blazor - passing dynamic values to another page/layout

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I am struggling with the following behaviour. I have a page called clientaddedit. This page has a div hidden by default (Cancel button also on div) and a button that shows the div. Then, I have a custom layout that has iframes to call this page and a set of custom navigation buttons to navigate between iframes. So, when the div from the client page is visible, the navigation buttons on the layout become disabled. When the div is hidden again, then the buttons should become enabled.

I tried creating a service class to update the state of the value:

```
public event Action<bool> IsDivVisibleChanged;

private bool isDivVisible = false;

public bool IsDivVisible
{
    get => isDivVisible;
    set
    {
        if (isDivVisible != value)
        {
            isDivVisible = value;
            IsDivVisibleChanged?.Invoke(isDivVisible);
        }
    }
}

protected virtual void OnIsDivVisibleChanged(bool isVisible)
{
    IsDivVisibleChanged?.Invoke(isVisible);
}
```

And then in my page I have this onclick,

```
private void ShowRenameClient()
{
    renameClient_Div = false;
    overlayService.IsDivVisible = true;
    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```

And then finally in the custom layout,

```
<button class='one right-side-bar-btns' @onclick="MyBool1" disabled="@(isDivVisible ? true :        false)">Client Add/Edit</button>   

private bool isDivVisible;   

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
   overlayService.IsDivVisibleChanged += HandleDivVisibilityChanged;
   isDivVisible = overlayService.IsDivVisible;
}

private void HandleDivVisibilityChanged(bool isVisible)
{
   isDivVisible = isVisible;
   InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```

From this code, I also put in overlayService.IsDivVisible on both the page and layout to test if the value changes. The value on the page with the button responsible for changing the value, works fine and the value is updated. However, the value on the custom layout stays the same value specified in the Service class, it does not update.

Comment: Hi, could you please include the relevant injection setup in program.cs and where you are injecting this in your components and layout. Also IsDivVisibleChanged definition in your service. What version of blazor are you using?

Comment: @BrianParker In my program.cs: 
builder.Services.AddScoped<OverlayService>();

In my _Imports.razor:
@ using BlazorStockDemoScreen.Services

I am injecting the service as follows in both layout and component: 
@ inject OverlayService overlayService

I am also using the latest Blazor Server App .Net6.0.

also the IsDivVisibleChanged's code i forgot to add, 
public event Action<bool> IsDivVisibleChanged;

Comment: try: `public event EventHandler<bool> IsDivVisibleChanged;`

Comment: @BrianParker I did try EventHandler<bool> but no success. The value still remains the same on the layout whilst the value on the current page is updating on each click.

Comment: Assuming this is a Blazor application [and not some form of  hybrid], can you explain "custom layout that has iframes to call this page".  What's the reasoning behind  using `IFrame`?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Well, I am fairly new to blazor so I made custom layouts because I am busy with a major application and one layout will not suffice. I have located iframes in the layouts for performance purposes. This application is purely c# blazor server app with a tiny bit of js.interop and css.

Comment: There are [almost] no reasons you should be using IFrames in a Blazor application.  Performance?  I'm not sure how. [Polite] "I am struggling with the following behaviour" because you're trying to use IFrames.  What you describe is standard diet for a Blazor application.  I haven't provided an example answer because I can't piece together what you're trying to do using the code you've provided.  Read about [mre].

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I thought the problem was clear in my question that the value being passed through to the layout from the Iframe is not updating during run time. However, this application is in the early stages of development so I am testing everything for the best possible outcome. If you feel like I should use more repeated code (Duplicating) instead of Iframes and that it might fix my problem, then I will try it but I won't guarantee the success on the long run for the application's lifecycle. Thanks regardless for your input, Cheers.